# Bootstrap Columns. I'm unable to replicate this simple webpage design. What am I missing?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, breakpoints, grid-layout

Problem: There is a picture of a dog and 4 small paragraphs under the dog. While expanding the screen to pop the 4 paragraphs **next** to the picture of a dog in a 2x2 layout (2 paragraphs on top, 2 paragraphs on bottom), only 2 of the 4 paragraphs are moving over, while the other 2 paragraphs are stuck underneath the photo. Or, while tinkering with the code below, the 4 paragraphs will pop *side-by-side* (horizontally) next to the photo (as opposed to 2x2), and I don't want that either.

Side note #1: I know the "col-mid-2" and "col-lg-2" code above is incorrect; they're there as a placeholder for now.

Side note #2: The paragraphs pop around fine using Mobile/XL and Small breaking points, but I'm having issues with the medium/large breaking points (per the first paragraph).

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!-- bootstrap version 5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Grid Layout</h1>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/Sg3XwuEpybU" alt="">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <p>
          <h5>Fun fact #1:</h5> Dogs are not color blind. Contrary to popular belief, they can actually see most colors!</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <p>
          <h5>Fun fact #2:</h5>Tail wags have multiple meanings. It could mean that they are feeling happy, sad, or angry.</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <p>
          <h5>Fun fact #3:</h5>Three dogs actually survived the Titanic sinking in April of 1912. They were all in first class.</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <p>
          <h5>Fun fact #4:</h5>Small dogs live longer. This is due to the belief that, the smaller the dog, the less the heart needs to work to pump blood.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: FYI, it's invalid HTML to include headings inside paragraphs. A good editor will make these things apparent. Be sure you understand each element type's semantic purpose.